# Complex chords: does the construction depend on scale degree?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

I apologize for a newbie's question.

Suppose we're in C major. We'd like to construct a Cmaj13 chord. For that, we take C Ionian and keep stacking thirds: `C`, `E`, `G`, `B`, `D`, `F`, `A`.

At the same time, in C major we can build an Fmaj13 chord. Fmaj7 is always `F`, `A`, `C`, `E`. But does what comes next depend on which scale we're basing this on? It seems to me that if we're thinking of F Lydian, so IV degree of C major, Fmaj13 would consist of `F`, `A`, `C`, `E`, `G`, `B`, `D`. But in F major this would be F Ionian, so `F`, `A`, `C`, `E`, `G`, `Bb`, `D`.

So, what would be "right" Fmaj13? Would that depend on scale degree we're building it on? Or should we say that the second option is "true" Fmaj13, and the first chord is Fmaj#11 13?

Re-wording it, would higher structure (9-11-13) for a major chord always form a minor triad? Does the game change if we think of minor chords?

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I haven’t found those during my search: should I delete my question?